# Prepared statement result in a table

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

Please, this is my first attempt on mysqli with php. I am trying to print results into a table but the table does not desplay any data in it.

I earlier tried

> printf("%s %s\n", $c_id, $ctitle);

and I got the correct results printed. But I want the results in a table.

I intend this to be a details page that will be linked to the main page items.My code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "joseph", " ", "collectionsdb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT c_id,ctitle,csubject,creference,cyear,cobjecttype,cmaterial,ctechnic,cwidth,cheight,cperiod,cmarkings,cdescription,csource,cartist,cfilename FROM collections ORDER BY c_id")) {   
    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Bind results to variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($c_id,$ctitle,$csubject,$creference,$cyear,$cobjecttype,$cmaterial,$ctechnic,$cwidth,$cheight,$cperiod,$cmarkings,$cdescription,$csource,$cartist,$cfilename);

?>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
<body>  

<?php
    /* fetch values */
    while ($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {

    // print image and data into a html table ?? 
?>
    <table border="1" align="left">
<tr>
    <td rowspan=16> <?php echo '<img src="./images/'.$rows['cfilename'].'" width="300" height="400" />';  ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr><td>ID</td><td><?php echo $rows['c_id']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>TITLE</td><td><?php echo $rows['ctitle']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>SUBJECT</td><td><?php echo $rows['csubject']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>REFERENCE No.</td><td><?php echo $rows['creference']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>YEAR</td><td><?php echo $rows['cyear']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>OBJECT TYPE</td><td><?php echo $rows['cobjecttype']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>MATERIAL USED</td><td><?php echo $rows['cmaterial']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>TECHNIC</td><td><?php echo $rows['ctechnic']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>WIDTH</td><td><?php echo $rows['cwidth']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>HEIGHT</td><td><?php echo $rows['cheight']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>PERIOD</td><td><?php echo $rows['cperiod']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>MARKINGS</td><td><?php echo $rows['cmarkings']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>DESCRIPTION</td><td><?php echo $rows['cdescription']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>SOURCE</td><td><?php echo $rows['csource']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>ARTIST</td><td><?php echo $rows['cartist']; ?></td></tr>
</table>

<?php
    }

    /* Close the statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
else {
    /* Error */
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

/* close our connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Thank you.

Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $rows array you have to use variables you bound earlier - i.e. $c_id,$ctitle,$csubject
You also have misplaced your `<table>` tag. Move it outside the loop.

As you can see, mysqli is quite unusable with prepared statements.
Either use it with manual placeholders or move to PDO.
It will make your code **a lot** cleaner, for example (this is ALL code you need):

```
<?php
$db = new DB();
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM collections ORDER BY c_id");
?>  
<table border="1" align="left">
<?php foreach ($data as $rows) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=16>
      <img src="/images/<?php echo $rows['cfilename'] ?>" width="300" height="400" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>ID</td><td><?php echo $rows['c_id']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>TITLE</td><td><?php echo $rows['ctitle']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>SUBJECT</td><td><?php echo $rows['csubject']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>REFERENCE No.</td><td><?php echo $rows['creference']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>YEAR</td><td><?php echo $rows['cyear']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>OBJECT TYPE</td><td><?php echo $rows['cobjecttype']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>MATERIAL USED</td><td><?php echo $rows['cmaterial']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>TECHNIC</td><td><?php echo $rows['ctechnic']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>WIDTH</td><td><?php echo $rows['cwidth']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>HEIGHT</td><td><?php echo $rows['cheight']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>PERIOD</td><td><?php echo $rows['cperiod']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>MARKINGS</td><td><?php echo $rows['cmarkings']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>DESCRIPTION</td><td><?php echo $rows['cdescription']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>SOURCE</td><td><?php echo $rows['csource']; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td>ARTIST</td><td><?php echo $rows['cartist']; ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```